# PHP Class Database interaction (using PDO)

Tags: php, oop, pdo

Hey guys, so I'm completely new to Object Oriented PHP -- I've read some tutorials, but I can't find anything that really goes into working with a database with PHP classes.

I'm trying to make something simple -- a quick news post class. You get the post from the database, etc. However, I'm getting an error whenever I try to interact with the database.

I read that PDO is the way to go with OO PHP; to that end, I've developed a database class, as detailed in this post: [Use of PDO in classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047264/use-of-pdo-in-classes)

```
class Database
{
    public $db;   // handle of the db connexion
    private static $dsn  = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test";
    private static $user = "admin";
    private static $pass = "root";
    private static $instance;

    public function __construct () 
    {
        $this->db = new PDO(self::$dsn,self::$user,self::$pass);
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if(!isset(self::$instance))
        {
            $object= __CLASS__;
            self::$instance=new $object;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    // others global functions
}
```

I then attempt to use it in my PHP class, in order to retrieve data on a news post:

```
<?php
require_once "database.php";

class news extends Database
{
    private $title;
    private $author;
    private $date;
    private $content;
    private $category;


    function __construct($id)
    {
        $db = Database::getInstance();
        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT title, author, date, content, category FROM news WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1");
        $query->bindParam(":id", $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        if ($query->execute())
        {
            $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            $this->set_title($result->title);
            $this->set_author($result->author);
            $this->set_date($result->date);
            $this->set_content($result->content);
            $this->set_category($result->category);
        }
    }
<...>
?>
```

Every time I try to run this script though, I get the following error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /news.class.php on line 16

Any ideas?

Comment: Side note:  if you want to implement the Database class as a singleton (i.e. xx::getInstance()), leave __construct() blank or even make it private so that getInstance() is the only way to access it.  Otherwise it's just a regular class with funny instantiation.

Answer (score 3):

```
$db = Database::getInstance();
$query = $this->db->prepare();
```

You'll have to use either `$db` or `$this->db` both times. `$db` is a variable in the local function. `$this->db` is an instance variable of the class. They're not the same. In this case, `$this->db` does not exist and as such has no member function `prepare`, as the error states.

You're trying to create `$this->db` in your parent's constructor, but since you're overriding the constructor in the child class, that code is not run. You would need to call `parent::__constructor` for that code to run.

Comment: Error has changed; Shouldn't prepare() exist though, since I have $db as a PDO object in the Database class?

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Database::prepare() in /home1/centasmn/public_html/other_sites/test/news.class.php on line 16

Comment: `Database::getInstance` returns an instance of the `Database` class, which by itself doesn't have a `prepare` method either. `$db->db` is the object you're looking for, but that's probably not how you wanted to use the object.

Answer (score 3):

Your design is flawed. Why does news extend Database? Database represents your global database connection. One single row of the news table is not a database connection. So it should not inherit from it. What you should do is follow the "favor composition over inheritance" principle.

Extending a singleton is not a good idea. As a matter of fact, singletons are a bad idea in general, because they make your code monolithic.

What you are doing is basically object-relational mapping. You should take a look at some existing PHP ORMs, I suggest [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).

Comment: And what if I don't want to use something as big as Doctrine, how would you do Database/Objects interactions?

Answer (score -1):

$db = Database::getInstance();
 need to be:
$db = new Database();

And this line $query = $this->db->prepare();
need to be 
$query = $db->prepare();

Then this $query->bindParam(":id", $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
need to be 
$query->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

I'm not sure why you need the getInstance() function in the Database class? The

new Database()

will give you a new instance.

Comment: I believe he's aiming for a singleton pattern with `getInstance`.

Comment: Probably -- but I want to learn good habits right from the get go, even if it means a steeper learning curve. Thanks for the answer though!