# OOP, PDO & MYSQL Usage

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I coudnt use my PDO mysql connection on my classes.. Could you help me to modify my code? (first of all, its connecting to database and checking session to detect member name in __construct function, then write last news..)

```
class Content {

public function __construct() {

public $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XXXX;
charset=utf8", "XXXX", "XXXX");

$db->exec('SET NAMES `UTF-8`');

if ($_SESSION[user_id])  {  
$query = $db->query("SELECT count(id),name FROM members 
WHERE id = '$_SESSION[user_id] LIMIT 1")->fetch(); }

 }

public function WriteContent() {
$news = $db->query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")->fetch();
echo 'hi'.$query[name].'<br/><br/>'.$news[headline].'<br/>'.$news[detail];
}
}
```

Comment: What error php show ?

Comment: empty page :S @Gerald Chablowski

Comment: Can you not used an injection more than to call pdo on your contrsucter. Moreover you shlould use new \Pdo(), like that it refer to the name space of javascript.

Comment: cound you give an very basic sample for pdo mysql connection in oop class usage. (1 times mysql connection, then use $db variable in all classes)

Comment: The best approch would be that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047264/use-of-pdo-in-classes

Comment: let me look.. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
You were missing the quotes of $_SESSION[user_id] and the argument in ->fetch($argument);
You sould use a try catch when using pdo so if you have a mistake you will know why

```
class Content {

public function __construct() {

public $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XXXX;
charset=utf8", "XXXX", "XXXX");

$db->exec('SET NAMES `UTF-8`');

if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){  
    $userId=$_SESSION['user_id'];
    $query = $db->query("SELECT count(id),name FROM members 
    WHERE id = $userId LIMIT 1")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    }   
}

public function WriteContent() {
$news = $db->query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo 'hi'.$query[name].'<br/><br/>'.$news[headline].'<br/>'.$news[detail];
}
}
```

Example of a connection using PDO and OOP

```
class Connection{
    protected $con; //connection variable

    public function Conexion(){
        try{
            $this->con=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Youtube","root","");
            $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);     
            $this->con->exec("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");
            return $this->con;
        }
        catch (PDOException $e){
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />Line: " .   $e->getLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Every time you need the connection you will have to do require('connetion.php');
and to use it in other class:

```
Class ViewDataBaseResults extends Connection{
    public function ViewDataBaseResults(){
        parent::__construct(); //You inherit the construct here
    }
    public function view(){
        $result=$this->con->query("SELECT * FROM TABLE"); //
        if($array=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));{
             echo "Hi: " . $array['name'] . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```